# marker is taking too big click area

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, coordinates, android-geofence

I want to reduce the. touch area of marker in focus. While click area is too big, I want to short the click area of marker on google map.

I am new to map, I want to know how could we reduce the padding of marker in focus in android .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- first I tried. to add one overlay inside xml   `<View android:id="@+id/transparentOverlay" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/transparent" />`

  ```
   then inside onMapReady, I implemented this code -  

   binding.transparentOverlay.setOnClickListener { view ->
               val mapClickPoint = Point(view.x.toInt(), view.y.toInt())
               val mapLatLng = map.projection.fromScreenLocation(mapClickPoint)
               if (this::carMarker.isInitialized) {
                   if (isPointInMarkerClickableArea(carMarker, mapLatLng)) {
                       // The click was within the custom clickable area of the marker
                       // Handle the marker click here
                       markerClickAction(carMarker)
                   }
               }
           }   private fun isPointInMarkerClickableArea(marker: Marker, clickLatLng: LatLng): Boolean {
       // Calculate the distance between the marker's position and the clickLatLng
       // If the distance is within a certain threshold, consider it a click on the marker
       val distanceThreshold = 50 // in pixels, adjust as needed
       val markerPosition = marker.position
       val markerScreenPosition = map.projection.toScreenLocation(markerPosition)
       val clickScreenPosition = map.projection.toScreenLocation(clickLatLng)
       val distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((markerScreenPosition.x - clickScreenPosition.x).toDouble(), 2.0) +
   Math.pow((markerScreenPosition.y - clickScreenPosition.y).toDouble(),
   2.0))
       return distance <= distanceThreshold }  private fun markerClickAction(carMarker: Marker) {
       // Implement your action when the marker is clicked
       // For example, show an info window, navigate to a detailed view, etc.
       Toast.makeText(this, "Click on marker: ${carMarker.title}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
  ```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).